# How can I clear all text in a buffer using `ansi-term`?

Tags: ansi-term

Emacs 27.1

`M-x ansi-term`

run some process that outputs lots of text.

Then `C-c` and type Linux command `clear`.

Only the current page is cleared, in the buffer. But I need to clear all text from the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

```el
(defun my-term-reset-terminal ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((inhibit-read-only t))
    (term-reset-terminal)))
```

In char mode you can call it after typing <kbd>C-c</kbd> (or maybe <kbd>C-x</kbd>).  E.g.:

<kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>M-x</kbd> `my-term-reset-terminal`

Or you might prefer:

```el
(with-eval-after-load "term"
  (define-key term-raw-escape-map (kbd "C-l") 'my-term-reset-terminal))
```

Which gives you the <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-l</kbd> binding when in char mode.

---

I think you should <kbd>M-x</kbd> `report-emacs-bug` though, as the code for `term-emulate-terminal` comments that the `clear` command will result in a call to `term-reset-terminal` and seemingly that doesn't happen.

Comment: In my case this help: (define-key term-mode-map (kbd "C-l") #'my-term-reset-terminal)

Comment: If I execute my-term-reset-terminal when ansi-term have some live ouput then  clear not working correctly. I need to stop output (e.g. by C-c) and the only then run my-term-reset-terminal. It not very convinient.

Comment: Typing `clear` in a terminal emulator *also* doesn't abort the process you're running in the terminal.  It would *not* be expected behaviour for that to happen.  If you want to programmatically send `C-c` to the inferior process you can use `(term-send-raw-string "\C-c")`.